# htaccess rewrite subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite two virtual subfolders /content/view/, and /content/section/. I now have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^htaccesstst/content/(view|section)+
RewriteRule ^$ http://www\.google\.nl [L,R=301]
```

This rewrites /content, /content/, /content/view/, /content/section/, which is correct. BUT it rewrites /content/ (with nothing after it) too. I don't want this! Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with:

```
RewriteRule ^htaccesstst/content/(view|section)/?$ http://www.google.nl [L,R=301]
```